# Installation Options

Tags: system-installation

I have created a new logical partition (H) on my hardrive and want to install Ubuntu in that partition. I also want to have access to my Windows 7 files and programmes. I would like some advice as to which installation option I should use.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a label for your logical drive from Windows. This way it will be easier to distinguish it from other drives. As a failsafe, remember its size.
Now boot from the LiveCD or LiveUSB.

- Start the Installtion. Continue the normal procedure.
- When Installation Options come up, click 'Do Something Else' and then Next

  [image: Installations options]
- This will appear:

  [image: Partition Manager]

  - Now double click the partition where you want to install Ubuntu and select "Ext4 Journaling System" in 'the Use as' dropdown.
  - Select '/' in the 'Mount Point' dropdown.
  - Click OK and then Next. Change other settings if you want.
  - Continue the Installation process.